# Функция isempty

Tags: python, matlab

Переписываю код из matlab в python. Чем можно заменить функцию `imsepty` (истино, если массив пустой) в питоне?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто проверяйте свой массив

```
s = []
    if s:
        print ('not empty')
    else:
        print('empty')

    empty

    s = [1,2,3]
    if s:
        print ('not empty')
    else:
        print('empty')

    not empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вообще без функции обойтись (если только функция не требуется как что-то обязательное, скажем, для передачи другой функции), вот так как-то:

`s = []
что-то делаем с s`

в месте проверки просто сказать:

`if not s`

Comment: В смысле это?

    s = []
    s and print s
    # nothing

Comment: Нет, это работать не будет.
print не возвращает значения, если я не путаю, так что сделать and не выйдет.

Идея в том, чтобы проверять саму s
Если она пуста, при проверке получим False

Comment: Согласен, с `print` не работает. Изменил пример :)

Важен не именно `print`, а проверка - если есть `l`, делаем вещи.

Comment: можно просто сделать:

if not s:
    что-то делаем